# Computer Beeps Attempting to Startup, Must Ctrl+Alt+Del to Boot

Tags: windows-7, boot

Windows 7 on hp Pavilion.

Beeps are continuous not staccato when I turn on the power, and it continues until I push the power button to turn it off again. I tried CTRL+ALT+DEL and it will boot that way.

I would like to know why it is doing this and if possible, how it can be fixed DIY.

Thanks!

Comment: Count the number of beeps, long or short, then google your motherboard's model number plus "beep codes". That should take you where you need to be.

Comment: If Desktop, unplug everything apart from power. Switch on. Does it still beep?

If Laptop, search for disassembly instructions for keyboard online, and remove the ribbon cable. Power on. Beep ?

Comment: The problem seems to have resolved itself. The beeps did not match any of the beep codes and I didn't remove the ribbon cable, just kept using it by pressing CTRL+ALT+DEL to boot when the beeping started. This morning it booted normally without beeps. Thanks for the suggestions!